# How to replace the style of the inline cell in a StyleSheet

Tags: front-end, formatting, stylesheet

I would like to change a StyleSheet in such a way that any text that is typed into the inline cell (the one created by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>) is shown in a different font (e.g. the font of my choice). At present I do not see, what definition should I change.

Comment: I have the impression that the code-related styles have a harder-coded font setting. There is some logic to this, as this style has to be able to display all kinds of mathematical symbols, usually not present in text fonts. It is easy to change the header fonts. The default.nb file says:"The cells in this section define styles used for input and output to the kernel.  Be careful when modifying, renaming, or removing these styles, because the front end associates special meanings with these style names. Some attributes for these styles are actually set in FormatType Styles. "

Answer (score 11):

**Using the Option Inspector:**

In the `Format` menu choose `Option Inspector`, select `Cell Options > New Cell Defaults` and edit the value of the option `DefaultNewInlineCellStyle`.

In the screenshot below, I changed the value of this option from `{}` to `"Subsection"` using the drop-down menu.
The first two cells on the left notebook show the inline cell styles before and after changing the value of the option  in the `Option Inspector`.

[image]

**Using `SetOptions`:**

To change the for the new inline cells for the active notebook, use

```
 SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DefaultNewInlineCellStyle -> "Section"]
```

Example cell containing an inline cell:

[image]

For the style change to apply to all new inline cells in the current front-end session, use

```
 SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, DefaultNewInlineCellStyle -> "Section"]
```

If you want to have the changes to persist across sessions, use

```
 SetOptions[$FrontEnd, DefaultNewInlineCellStyle -> "Section"]
```

Finally, to reset any of the changes, use

```
 SetOptions[xxx, DefaultNewInlineCellStyle -> Inherited]
```

where `xxx` is `EvaluationNotebook[]`, or `$FrontEndSession` or `$FrontEnd`.

**Setting your own custom styles:**

```
 SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 DefaultNewInlineCellStyle -> {FontFamily -> "SketchFlowPrint", FontSize -> 24}]
```

[image: custom style]

Comment: Thank you, that is, indeed, the possibility. However, my question is still valid: is it possible to change the StyleSheet in such a way that using this StyleSheet I never should think about fixing this style for each new notebook? It would be great, if such a possibility exists.

Comment: @A.Boulbitch, I agree that your question stands. I am hoping someone more comfortable with style sheets will come up with an answer.

Answer (score 9):

To do this via a StyleSheet add this to your stylesheet:

```
Cell[StyleData["InlineCell"],
 TextAlignment->Left,
 LanguageCategory->"Formula",
 ScriptLevel->1,
 StyleMenuListing->None,
 FontFamily->"Helvetica",
 FontSize->16]


Cell[StyleData["InlineCellEditing"],
 StyleMenuListing->None,
 Background->RGBColor[1,0,0]]
```

[image]

[image]

To create your stylesheet you could follow these steps if you prefer doing things programmatically:

[Quickly editing the stylesheet and saving it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1649/quickly-editing-the-stylesheet-and-saving-it/1659#1659)

or if you prefer a more "standard" way of adding a stylesheet you could follow the steps outlined by @kguler in the comment below.

Comment: +1 @Mike, thank you! This works great. I had come across these two cells in `Core.nb` stylesheet but was afraid to edit that file:) It would be useful to add the steps to be followed: eg. select  `Edit Stylesheet` from the `Format` menu; copy/paste the two cells separately into `Style Definitions for Untitled-x.nb`; and then click the `Install Stylesheet` button etc

Comment: Never edit Core.nb. What you should do in all cases is add the relevant style to your specific stylesheet. The stylesheet will have a dependency on Default.nb which in turn uses Core.nb.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I looked for. Alexei