# Customizing the Screen Environment

Tags: notebooks, customization

Is it possible to make Mathematica notebooks as stylish as this below with custom backgrounds and predictive text coloring? As shown in the snippet below? And possibly have the option to save the preferred setting and choose it on each start up, or possibly have it automatically loaded when the notebook is launched.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Re: appearance, you can do this with a style sheet. Below are some cells with my styles for a) running the terminal in Mma and b) sending stuff to a word document.

[image]

If that is what you are looking for I'll post a more detailed example.

Re: "predictive text coloring"

I presume you mean syntax styling of Mathematica code? If so this can be configured from the preferences menu, the options inspector, or a stylesheet.

If you can confirm that is what you require I'll post something more detailed. In the meantime these links may be useful:

[Quickly editing the stylesheet and saving it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1649/quickly-editing-the-stylesheet-and-saving-it/1659#1659)

[How to replace the style of the inline cell in a StyleSheet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-replace-the-style-of-the-inline-cell-in-a-stylesheet/3544#3544)

**Edit**

```
CreateDocument@
 Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
   Cell[StyleData["MyInputStyle", 
     StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Input"]],
    AutoStyleOptions -> {
      "CommentStyle" -> {FontColor -> RGBColor[0.501961, 0, 0.25098], 
        FontSize -> 11, FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS", 
        ShowAutoStyles -> False, ShowSyntaxStyles -> False, 
        AutoNumberFormatting -> False},
      "FunctionLocalVariableStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
         RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0]}, 
      "LocalVariableStyle" -> {FontColor -> RGBColor[0., 0.502, 0.], 
        ShowAutoStyles -> False, ShowSyntaxStyles -> False, 
        AutoNumberFormatting -> False}, 
      "PatternVariableStyle" -> {FontColor -> 
         RGBColor[0.502, 0, 0.251], FontSlant -> "Italic", 
        ShowAutoStyles -> False, ShowSyntaxStyles -> False, 
        AutoNumberFormatting -> False}, 
      "StringStyle" -> {FontColor -> RGBColor[0.7, 0.35, 0.], 
        FontSize -> 11, FontFamily -> "Century Gothic", 
        ShowAutoStyles -> False, ShowSyntaxStyles -> False, 
        AutoNumberFormatting -> False}},
    Background -> GrayLevel[0],
    FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 1, 0],
    MenuSortingValue -> 1500
    ]}, StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]
```

Save this document as a stylesheet and then to use it change you input cells to myInputStyle:

[image]

You may also want to set your own colours of course. I just pasted one of my color schemes and set the font to yellow and the background to black. It looks pretty bad but the framework is there for you to modify it.

[image]

Comment: Yes. That is what I am looking for. Something along the lines of the text inside the shell.

Comment: ok. Try the code I posted in the edit and let me know if that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I sure am learning to do neat nifty things like this with Mathematica instead of only using it to compute things. It is so much more powerful than that. I am going to read up on programming in Mathematica pretty soon `:)`. One thing, I did not see how to save it as a stylesheet? Can I `Export` it as one, & what's the extension for stylesheets if there is one?

Comment: @nightowl If you open a stylesheet you will see an "Install Stylesheet" button with an input field to give the stylesheet a name.

Comment: I ran the code and it prompted me to "install stylesheet" but i do not see where I can choose it under Format > Style > MyInputStyle

Comment: @nightowl did you first select the stylesheet? After you install the stylesheet you then have to select it otherwise you are still using the default one.