# Sharing styles between notebooks (Mathematica v9)

Tags: stylesheet, configuration

It appears from the documentation that we share styles via stylesheets. I am trying to set up a customised default stylesheet for my notebooks.

I have tried simple ideas, and more complex ones, without success.

1. If I edit the provided default.nb, my changes to it are not saving.
2. If I make model notebook of my own, say aModel.nb, and customise that notebook's styles, a copy of that model does not have those styles.
3. If I "install" the stylesheet of aModel.nb, and apply that to some other notebook, it has no effect.

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5930/5 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9942/5

Comment: Also, several useful and informative answers can be found by searching for ["stylesheet" in Mike Honeychurch's posts](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A77+stylesheet)