# How make the default fonts of v11 like in v10: Courier for .nb AND sans serif for .m/.wl editor

Tags: front-end, fonts, version-11

I would like to make the *default* font of .m/.wl editor in Mathematica 11 to be that of Mathematica 10 (a smaller narrower fixed width sans serif font).  Simultaneously, I would like to make the *default* font of .nb files the Courier font of version 10 and before.  By "*default*", I mean the font should be used automatically every time I open a new window in Mathematica 11.

Following the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123850/how-to-get-rid-of-new-default-version-11-input-output-fonts-and-keep-the-trad) I am able to change the default font of all files, but not in the more specific way requested above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of new default Version 11 Input/Output fonts -> and keep the traditional Courier font](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123850/how-to-get-rid-of-new-default-version-11-input-output-fonts-and-keep-the-trad)

Comment: @Edmund not a complete duplicate.  I also want to change the .m/.wl editor font to the old v10 font which is sans serif but narrower and smaller.

Comment: To the OP:  I had not considered that the default font for .m files might be different to that for .nb files. On v10.4 Mac, the default font for .m is Menlo (as opposed to Courier for .nb Input cells). Two comments:  (i) Looking at Menlo, some characters do have serifs such as the letter i and l. (ii) I have made my default font for Input cells traditional Courier ... and I must say that the .m package code is much easier to read in Courier (for me) than in Menlo. This is partly because Menlo is squished to be narrow/condensed, which might also be the attraction to you (to avoid H scrolling :)

Comment: @wolfies Yes, they are different.  I have a *very bad* habit of writing my code using far fewer line breaks than most coders.  So yes, I consider it an attraction since there's less horizontal scrolling.