# How do I create inline TraditionalForm expressions, and control their formatting?

Tags: formatting, stylesheet, traditional-form

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace the style of the inline cell in a StyleSheet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-replace-the-style-of-the-inline-cell-in-a-stylesheet)

I'm trying to figure out the best practice for creating short, inline expressions that display as `TraditionalForm` within paragraphs of text, and to understand how to control the style used for expressions. For example, what I'd like to be able to is

- select some text and press a key or choose a style and have that selection display as `TraditionalForm`, and
- while typing, within a paragraph, be able to toggle `TraditionalForm` on and off.

Ideally I'd also like to have the formatting or style of such expressions controlled by a (character, as opposed to paragraph) style.

One approach that would seem to do this is just to apply the default "InlineFormula" style, but that has no apparent effect, and clearly is intended for some other purpose. Another might be to select text and choose "Cell > TraditionalForm Display", but that changes the whole cell. Selecting text and choosing an item from the "Typesetting Forms" palette works (or using the corresponding command keys), but all of the items in that palette add additional elements structure (e.g. superscripts) in addition to converting the selected text to `TraditionalForm`.

Is there some straightforward way to just toggle inline `TraditionalForm` on and off? Can I control the (character) style of such selections.

Comment: Isn't the default inline cell in text cells already in traditional form? To convert the selected text you can always do ctrl+shirt+t or right click, convert to->TraditionalForm

Comment: @Rojo: I have two problems with that: (1) it has side effects, for example I loose the parentheses when converting "f(x)"; (2) while that does produce `TraditionalForm`, I don't see how to control the style  (e.g. making all inline expressions bold or blue).

Comment: @Rojo: And a third: (3) I can't use it do do the second thing in the question. If I ctrl+shift+t the selection jumps out of the text, so I can't continue typing.

Comment: Please come to the chat, there are probably some confusions here

Comment: This Q/A may be useful: [How to replace the style of the inline cell in a StyleSheet](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3510/)

Comment: @kguler: That's it (along with the included ctrl+9).

Comment: @raxa, is it ok to vote to close this question as a  duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: @kguler: Yes. Will it remain for searching (I never would have found that answer, so another entrypoint would be helpful)?

Comment: I think (not certain though) closed questions stay on the site with a link to the related open question (at least for some time).