# How can I style text like in a system usage message?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet

I'm writing an article, and I really like this style that you get when you type `?AnyFunction`.

[image: I want to achieve style like this]

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for the `tutorial/EnteringTwoDimensionalInput` in the Mathematica Documentation?

Comment: Or is it the yellow background and border/text styles that you like?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The style name is `PrintUsage`. It is defined in the stylesheet notebook `Core.nb` which you can find in the directory:

```
$InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets
```

It has the following settings:

```
CellFrame -> {{0, 0}, {0, 3}}
CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[1, 0.6000000000000001, 0] 
Background -> RGBColor[1, 0.993332, 0.899718]
```

You can use the `OptionInspector` to set `DefaultNewCellStyle` or `DefaultReturnCreatedCellStyle` to `PrintUsage`. You can also change these settings  at the notebook, front-end session or front-end level using

```
SetOptions[xx,DefaultNewCellStyle->"PrintUsage"]
```

where `xx` is `EvaluationNotebook[]` or `$FrontEndSession`, or `$DefaultFrontEnd`.

A third alternative is to use the right-click context menu on a cell bracket,choose `Style->Other` and type `PrintUsage` in the dialog box to change the style of that cell.

One important issue with the above approach is that a cell with `PrintUsage` style is not editable. So, you may want to define your custom style using something like 
[this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1659/125) by Mike Honeychurch:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   StyleDefinitions -> 
   Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
   Cell[StyleData["myPrintUsageStyle"], Editable -> True, Evaluatable -> True,
   CellFrame -> {{0, 0}, {0, 3}}, CellMargins -> {{66, 10}, {10, 5}},
   CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[1, 0.6000000000000001, 0], 
   Background -> RGBColor[1, 0.993332, 0.899718]]}, 
   Saveable -> True, StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]];
```

and use it in place of `PrintUsage` using any of the usage options mentioned above, e.g.,

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],  DefaultNewCellStyle -> "myPrintUsageStyle"]
```

Comment: Thank you, you have totally answered my question. :)

Comment: @balboa, glad to know it worked for you. Thanks for the accept.