# in v9, backspace causes cell to become section style

Tags: front-end, version-9

In the front end of v9, in any given cell that contains content, if I hit backspace to clear the content until there is nothing left, and then hit backspace one more time, the cell becomes a 'section'.

Is this a new feature?  How do I use it?

**Edit**

Would someone verify this effect in the comments?

Comment: What is the style of the "any given cell"? Does it happen in a regular Input cell? I can see that happening in SubSection

Comment: "any given cell" is a regular Input cell (one where I run expressions).

Comment: Then that shouldn't happen. The cell option that controls this is `StyleKeyMapping`. Try evaluating `CurrentValue[StyleKeyMapping]` and see what comes out

Comment: @Rojo and @kguler, After running `CurrentValue[StyleKeyMapping]`, I get `{"=" -> "WolframAlphaShort"}`.

Comment: This depends on the style of the current cell. I get this behaviour for cells with `Title`, `Subtitle`, `Subsubtitle` or `Section`, `Subsection`, `Subsubsection` style. `StyleKeyMapping` option in the style definitions controls the behaviour in response to `Backspace` and `Tab`. See, for example, CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Subsection", StyleKeyMapping}]

Comment: @QuantumDot, that is the key mapping for `Input` cells (which happens to be the setting for `DefaultNewCellStyle`); it means "typing = in the beggining of a new cell" changes the style of the cell from `Input` to  `WolframAlphaShort`

Comment: Why does "Input" gets transformed into "Subsection" when pressing backspace? I thought there should be a backspace entry under StyleKeyMapping.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Version 9, in cells with `Title`, `Subtitle`, `Subsubtitle`  or `Section`, `Subsection`, `Subsubsection`, ..., `Subsubsubsubsection`  (perhaps others) style, `Backspace` in the beginning of the cell changes the cell style to the style of the next level up the hierarchy (e.g., `Subsubsection > Subsection > Section`). Similarly, `Tab` changes the style of the cell to that of the lower level; e.g., `Section > Subsection > Subsubsection > ...`

`StyleKeyMapping` suboption in the style definitions controls the behaviour in response to `Backspace` and `Tab`

```
  somestyles ={"Title", "Subtitle", "Subsubtitle",   "Section", "Subsection", "Subsubsection",
  "Subsubsubsection",   "Subsubsubsubsection"}; 
  Grid[ Prepend[{Style[#,#], Column[CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, #, StyleKeyMapping}], 
        Center]} & /@ somestyles, 
   Style[#, Bold, 16] & /@ {"Style", "StyleKeymapping"}], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful!  Unfortunately, I find this highly annoying.  Is there any way to turn this feature completely off, for all notebooks, for both my computers?

Comment: The style definitions for `Title`, `Section` etc. are in the file `Default.nb`. Although you can replace the appropriate lines in that file with `StyleKeyMapping->{}`, I would not recommend any tempering with the installation files. Instead, you can define your custom style along the lines used in these related Q/As: [How can I style ...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4821/125) and [Quickly editing the stylesheet and saving it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1649/125)

Comment: I'm fascinated that a Tab in an empty subsubsection produces a subsubsubsection. I verified that it really does (the toolbar Style popup goes blank because it has no such menu item). But what the heck is a subsubsubsection?

Comment: @m_goldberg try another tab

Comment: @Rojo. Another Tab has no effect -- style stays at subsubsubsection. (OS X 10.6.8)

Comment: @m_goldberg you sure? I have a Subsubsubsubsection. W8

Comment: @Rojo. I tried again and got Subsubsubsubsection. I guess I can't count beyond three in the wee hours of the morning.

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to disable this feature? I agree with QuantumDot - it is very irritating.