# What is the simplest way to set the toolbar of a notebook to an image?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, docked-cell

For custom stylesheets, it's nice to have a graphic banner in the Docked Cell. According to the doc page tutorial/IntroductionToToolbars, this is how you do it, but it seem a bit overkill:

```
img = Rasterize[
   Framed["\tMy Header", Background -> LightBlue, FrameStyle -> White,
     ImageSize -> {2000, 30}]];
image = Cell[
   BoxData[ToBoxes[
      img] /. {(ImageSize -> {___, ___}) -> (ImageSize -> 
         ImageDimensions[img])}], "DockedCell", CellMargins -> -2, 
   CellFrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}];
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], DockedCells -> {image}]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure from your question if you *need* the docked cell to be an image.  I cannot see why you would unless you already have a rendered image, and that is not what you show.  Here is what I use:

```
myCell = Cell[
   "Title Goes Here", "DockedCell",
   CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[0.996109, 0.500008, 0],
   Background -> GrayLevel[0.750011],
   CellFrame -> {{0, 0}, {3, 0}},
   CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 0}},
   TextAlignment -> -0.5,
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica",
   FontSize -> 30
 ];

SetOptions[InputNotebook[], DockedCells -> myCell]
```

[image]

---

If you do in fact need to set an image as the docked cell the method you have looks reasonable, but I believe it can be simplified by using `Magnification -> 1` and a simpler form for `CellFrameMargins`.

Using this image: (drag into a Notebook and set `img =`)

[image]

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[],
  DockedCells -> 
    Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Image[img, Magnification -> 1],
     "DockedCell",
     CellFrame -> 0,
     CellFrameMargins -> 0
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: How would you do it simpler for a rendered image? I guess that's what he was getting at...

Comment: @R.M okay I tried to address that too.

Comment: I wasn't quite clear — what you have here is fine and the `BoxData@ToBoxes` approach is what the OP had in the question. But they were talking about a custom stylesheet, and I haven't found a way to get any evaluatable content (which `img` here is) into a stylesheet. It is essentially inert and the way that images are inserted in to stylesheets is by exporting the image as an encoded string and wrapping it in `GraphicsData`... something along the lines of `Cell[GraphicsData["Bitmap","thousandsOfCharactersOfEncodedJibberish"],...]`.

Comment: @R.M ah, I think I understand now finally.  I think what you propose is standard.

Comment: Do you know what that encoding is? I haven't been able to export an image into any reasonable string that `GraphicsData` can understand... All I can see from poking around are pre-encoded stuff in existing stylesheets, but no info on how to convert one of my own

Comment: @R.M I'm working on it. :-/

Comment: awesome! Looking forward to it :)

Answer (score 9):

Nothwithstanding the answer from Mr.Wizard and discussion with @R.M it seems like you want to make a stylesheet with a docked cell ...right?

```
img = Plot[Sin[x^2], {x, -3, 3},
  Axes -> False,
  AspectRatio -> 0.25,
  BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 9],
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {{"x axis", None}, {"y axis", None}},
  ImageSize -> 200,
  ImagePadding -> {{40, 1}, {30, 1}}]
```

Note that I have made this image just for testing purposes. If you have a JPEG or similar then just past it directly where you see `img` below. Once you have your image:

```
CellPrint[
 Cell[StyleData[All, "Working"],
  DockedCells -> {First[ToBoxes[
      TextCell[Row[{img, Spacer[20], Style["My Docked Cell", 24]}], 
       Background -> GrayLevel[0.8], CellMargins -> 0]
      ]]}]
 ]
```

[image]

This generated cell can be added to your stylesheet. Before cutting and pasting this cell into the stylesheet make sure to click on the cell bracket and go to the options inspector and set `GeneratedCells->False` and `CellAutoOverwrite->False`.

[image]

You need to do this because having these set to `True` in the stylesheet with lead to some screwy behaviour.

Alternatively to make it entirely programmatic you can do [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1649/quickly-editing-the-stylesheet-and-saving-it/1659#1659):

```
CreateDocument@Notebook[{
   Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
   Cell[StyleData[All, "Working"],
    DockedCells -> {First[ToBoxes[
        TextCell[Row[{img, Spacer[20], Style["My Docked Cell", 24]}], 
         Background -> GrayLevel[0.8], CellMargins -> 0]
        ]]}]},
  StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]
```

[image]

and save the resulting notebook as a stylesheet.

As far as creating cells like `Cell[GraphicsData["Bitmap","thousandsOfCharactersOfEncodedJibberish"],...]` goes I do not know how to make the resulting cell have the graphics information in this format. For my purposes this has never been a problem but I guess for large graphics there could be some advantages w.r.t to overall size.