# CDF Infokit question

Tags: notebooks, cdf-format, customization

In the *CDF Infokit*, one finds the `BriggsCochraneCalculus.cdf` document, which shows a textbook on calculus. I've got two questions about how it was made:

1. How has the bar at the top been made? Instead of the usual *CDF* commands, like zoom, etc., one finds the title (*Calculus*, etc), the name of the author,...
2. How have the different subsections been made, so they could open and close while clicking on the text of the subsection (`"Tangent Lines"`, `"Tangent Lines and Rates of Change"`, etc)? I have tried looking into the `Opener` and `Button` documentation, but I couldn't remake this functionality...

Comment: Related: [what-is-the-simplest-way-to-set-the-toolbar-of-a-notebook-to-an-image](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6318/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-set-the-toolbar-of-a-notebook-to-an-image) or the documentation [tutorial/IntroductionToToolbars](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToToolbars.html)

Comment: Also related: [courseware of the future](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=104&video=776)

Comment: You can find the answer to your second question in the video in the link above given by cormullian.  I've been developing a similar toolbar with links using his code as a model.  If you're interested I can show you what I have.