# Giving a custom style a colored gradient background

Tags: color, stylesheet

In *Mathematica*, customizing Sections, Subsections, Titles and so on, can be done with Format > Style > .... Changing the background color of a style is one of the things you can do. Here is an example where I have colored the background orange:

[image]

But I want to change the background to show a color gradient. I mean, instead of having the same orange in all of the background, there should be a gradient so the orange fades from top to bottom. Gradient styles will be found in Palettes > Color Schemes. But I can't get it to work for changing the color of a cell background.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to specify a gradient background (it may be in recent versions, but I don't think it is in v7 -- which I use).  Nevertheless you can specify a bitmap fill for full control: [(6318)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6318)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQs3gVobcfg&feature=youtu.be&t=25s

Comment: @belisarius Crikey! =:-O

Comment: @goldberg, thank you for your editing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how exactly to integrate this with a stylesheet background, but here is a way to achieve gradients using `Graphics`:

```
Overlay@{
  Graphics[
   Raster@{List@@@Table[Blend["AvocadoColors",i],{i,0,1,.005}]},
   AspectRatio->1/2,
   ImageSize->Full],
  Graphics[
   Text@Style["Gradient!",FontSize->Scaled@.2],
   AspectRatio->1/2,
   ImageSize->Full]}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I stumbled on a different way to do this that would be easier for simple layouts (tidied up with kguler's suggestion):

```
Graphics[{
  Polygon[
    {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
    VertexColors -> {Yellow, Yellow, Green, Green}], 
  Text[
    Style["Gradient!", FontSize -> Scaled@.2], 
    Scaled[{.5, .5}]]}, ImageSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Comment: You can do without `Overlay` putting `Text[..]` and `Polygon[...]` in a single `Graphics`: `Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, VertexColors -> {Yellow, Yellow, Green, Green}], Text[Style["Gradient!", FontSize -> Scaled@.2], Scaled[{.5, .5}]]}, ImageSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1/2]`

Comment: @kguler I was just exercising my fingers :P

Answer (score 4):

In versions 11.1+, you can use [`LinearGradientImage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearGradientImage.html) and add the text as [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html):

```
Show[LinearGradientImage["BlueGreenYellow", 6 {100, 50}], 
 Epilog -> {Text[Style["Gradient!", FontFamily -> "Old English Text MT",  
     FontSize -> Scaled@.22], Scaled[{.5, .5}]]}]
```

[image]

Replace `"BlueGreenYellow"` with `{Black, Red, Orange, White}` to get

[image]

**Update:** In versions 12.2.0+, gradient filling is available as a graphics directive:

```
Graphics[{LinearGradientFilling["BlueGreenYellow"], Rectangle[],
  Text[Style["Gradient!", FontSize -> Scaled@.2], Scaled[{.5, .5}]]}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Comment: O my God!!! Surprising and amazing!!! Can we make use of such command in plotting. For example, `Plot3D[Cos[x]Sin[y], {x...},{y,...}]` I mean to have a plot gradient with arbitrary colors

Comment: @Unbelievable, you mean something like `Plot3D[Cos[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Texture[LinearGradientImage[{Black, Red, Orange, White}]], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#3, #2} &), Mesh -> None]`?

Comment: ... or you can use a custom color function using `Blend`. For example, `Plot3D[Cos[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi},  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Black, Red, Orange, White}, #3] &), 
 Mesh -> None]`

Comment: You are right. I saw this function but I did not know that a set of colors can be chosen. Very amazing

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to do this is to use `Panel`:

```
Panel[
 Style["asdasd", FontSize -> 100, White],
 Appearance -> Rasterize@LinearGradientImage["BlueGreenYellow", 6 {100, 50}],
 ImageSize -> {500, 100}
 ]
```

[image]

This `Panel` content can be messed with however you like. You can also make it so inside a certain `Cell` every `Panel` has the same `Appearance` by setting it at the style environment level. This works best if you use the `BaseStyle` option to `Panel`, since that lets you create targeted environments, but I'm just gonna show it like this:

```
Style[
 Panel[
  Style["asdasd", FontSize -> 100, White],
  ImageSize -> {500, 100}
  ],
 PanelBoxOptions -> {
   Appearance -> Rasterize@LinearGradientImage["BlueGreenYellow", 6 {100, 50}]
   }
 ]
```

[image: same image]