# Modifying a spacing of cells and background of a notebook

Tags: notebooks, stylesheet

A simple question: How do I reduce this spacing and how to change the background?

[image]

I think it is in the Options Inspector, but I cannot find the exact location to make the modification.

As for the background, how could I add images like this:

[image]

Comment: Which Stylesheet are you using in the first example?  Is that Standard Report?

Comment: I believe the second part of your question is a duplicate of [(6961)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6961/121).  Also related: [(6318)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6318/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes this is the stylesheet.

Comment: I will check these links...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gap in the first example may be controlled with the Option [`CellFrameMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellFrameMargins.html).  This can be done for one cell at a time or by creating a custom Style Sheet.  Either is assisted by use of the [Option Inspector](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/OptionInspector.html).

Selecting your Title cell (use the selection bracket to its right), then opening the Option Inspector and searching for CellFrameMargins should show you something like:

[image]

The result of changing its value to `-5`:

[image]