# How to create a banner cell in a custom StyleSheet?

Tags: stylesheet

I would like to make a custom StyleSheet based on the JournalArticle for making internal documents for a company I am working at. In this template I would like to have a banner cell containing an image, such as this one:

[image]

How should I proceed?

**Edit**: To address the question of Cuba.

1. Yes, what I have in mind is creating a the DockedCell type cell in the StyleSheet.
2. This is, indeed, an image. I will fix its size, such that it fits the A4 page with 3 cm margins. The image can be saved as a pdf, or a jpg, or whatever else suitable format.
3. My question is how to include such a cell into the StyleSheet?

Comment: @Kuba Please have a look at the edit

Comment: Thanks, so what about https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6318/5478, looks like a duplicate but can't focus at the moment so let me know ;)

Comment: @Kuba  I agree that these answers (especially, the one of Mike Honeychurch) address my question. In principle, the question may be closed, but there is one problem still left. When I saved as a pdf the notebook with such a cell, no cell shows up in the pdf version. So the question is now, how to do this to be able to see the banner in the pdf?

Comment: DockedCells does not behave like a page header since it is always on top so I am afraid you will have to use a macro/template to create notebooks with your desired headers.